# i have a slider in flutter and i want to write a function for users to select ratings from 1 to 5

Tags: flutter, dart, slider

i want users to user the slider bar to select between 1 to 5 to give feedback but by default the slider is set to 1.i want to create a function for users to be sure of their feedback before they submit.
is there a function i can write to ask the user if they are sure of the feedback before submitting?

```
class SurveyFeedbackDialog {
  
  ValueNotifier<bool> _processingNotifier = ValueNotifier(false);
  ValueNotifier<double> _scaleNotifier = ValueNotifier(0);
  Widget get _scaleNumbers {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: _scaleNotifier,
      builder: ((_, double value, __) {
        int intVal = value.floor();
        return Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: Iterable<int>.generate(10)
              .map((i) => _number(i + 1, intVal == (i + 1)))
              .toList(),
        );
      }),
    );
  }

 
               
  Widget get _scaleSlider {
    return ValueListenableBuilder<double>(
      valueListenable: _scaleNotifier,
      builder: (context, double value, _) {
        return SliderTheme(
          data: SliderThemeData(
            trackShape: CustomTrackShape(),
          ),
          child: Slider(
            activeColor: Color(0XFF838181),
            inactiveColor: Color(0XFF838181),
            thumbColor: Colors.white,
            value: value,
            min: 1,
            max: 10,
            divisions: (10 - 1) ~/ 1,
            onChanged: (double value) {
              _scaleNotifier.value = value;
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  
      
  Widget get _submit {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: _processingNotifier,
      builder: ((_, bool value, __) {
        return AppButton(
          title: 'Submit',
          disabled: value,
          isProcessing: value,
          pressed: () {
            _processingNotifier.value = true;

            void _userFeedback() {}

            // send feedback to server
            var requestParam = SurveyFeedbackRequest(
              answer: _scaleNotifier.value.floor().toString(),
              surveyId: _survey.id,
              globalToken: AppConfig.globalToken,
              mobileno: AppConfig.playerInfo!.msisdn!.replaceAll("+", ""),
            );

            _surveyBloc.submitFeedback(requestParam);

            EventLogger.instance
                .TrackEvent(pageName: 'SurveyFeedback', event: 'completed');
          },
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

i used if and else but it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
    Widget get _submit {
        return ValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenable: _processingNotifier,
          builder: ((_, bool value, __) {
            return AppButton(
              title: 'Submit',
              disabled: value,
              isProcessing: value,
              pressed: () {
                if (_scaleNotifier.value ==0){ <----------------- add this condition
                  // show error message
                  return;
                } 
                _processingNotifier.value = true;
    
                void _userFeedback() {}
    
                // send feedback to server
                var requestParam = SurveyFeedbackRequest(
                  answer: _scaleNotifier.value.floor().toString(),
                  surveyId: _survey.id,
                  globalToken: AppConfig.globalToken,
                  mobileno: AppConfig.playerInfo!.msisdn!.replaceAll("+", ""),
                );
    
                _surveyBloc.submitFeedback(requestParam);
    
                EventLogger.instance
                    .TrackEvent(pageName: 'SurveyFeedback', event: 'completed');
              },
            );
          }),
        

);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you.is there a function i can include  ensure player selects a value before they can submit.